# Testing react ag-grid with Jest/Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, ag-grid

I am building out a test suite in my React Typescript application, using Jest and Enzyme to unit test my components.

However my main component has an Ag-Grid component embedded within it and a number of action buttons. The action buttons however are bound to the grid selection, so if you click "Approve", it first checks to see what has been selected in the grid, and then sends the entries to Redux via a dispatch action.

I can assert what was passed to the dispatch action callback, but the problem is I cannot see how I can mimic selection using Jest and Enzyme. These seem to only render static content using shallow/mount and I don't see how you can make this interative.

Is this even possible, or is there a different tool I should be using - or even a different way of architecting my code so it makes it unit testable?

An example

```
interface IItemGridProps {
  signoffApprove : (entries:ItemEntity[]) => void,
  items: ItemEntity[]  
}

export class ItemGrid extends React.Component<IItemGridProps,IItemGridState> {
  private gridApi: GridApi;

  private doApprove()
  {
      if (this.gridApi.getSelectedNodes().length > 0)
      {
        this.props.signoffApprove(this.getSelectedEntries());
      }
  }

  private getSelectedEntries() {
    return this.gridApi.getSelectedNodes().map(s => s.data)
  }

  private onGridReady(params: any) {
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
    this.gridApi = params.api;
  }

  public render() {
    <div className="ag-dark">
          <AgGridReact 
            gridOptions={this.props.gridOptions} 
            rowData={this.props.items}
            onGridReady={this.onGridReady}    
            onModelUpdated={this.initColumnSize}       
          />
        </div>
        <div class
  }
```